# Can I declare an array first and give its value later?

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, assignment-operator

I tried doing this but got an error. Why can't I do this?

```
int main()
{
char sweet[5];
sweet = "kova";
printf("My favorite sweet is %s\n", sweet);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: To put it simply i cant find that question. I'm just a beginner and there are a lot of things to worry about.

Comment: That is not just a _declaration_, but also a _definition_.

Answer (score 8):

Nope, you cant. Simply because array names are **non-modifiable l-value**. Which cannot be used as left operand in any expression. Therefore, you cannot keep it on the left side of a `=` expression.

However, If you want to copy the string `kova` to the array `sweet[]`, you can use `strcpy()` like this.

```
strcpy(sweet,"kova");
```

Answer (score 7):

You should copy using **strcpy**. Initialization is allowed only at the time of defining the array

```
int main()
{
char sweet[5];
strcpy(sweet,"kova");
printf("My favorite sweet is %s\n", sweet);

return 0;
}
```

Or you can do this

```
char sweet[] = "kova";
```

Comment: OP is interested in having the later at a leter time, so IMHO, `strcpy()`  is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

In C , you cannot *assign* a value to an array using the assigment operator `=`. Only , initialization through assignment at definition time is allowed.

You may want to use [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) to copy the content to the array.

Answer (score 1):

Well I guess you are trying to reinitialize the character array. In that case:

**Why This Is Impossible:**

An array can not be modified in a normal way. By the following statement:

```
sweet = "kova";
```

You really meant that the pointer sweet should now point to the first index of `"kova"` that is impossible. You can initialize this only on the time of declaration i.e. the following code will work fine.

```
char sweet[] = "kova";
```

After initialization you can not put an array name on the left side of a `=` it will be an error.

**What You Should Do:**

So this is clear that we can not simply modify an array's value however you can use built-in functions to do such task. In your case [strcpy](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcpy.htm) will do the job for you. Here's a rewrite attempt of your code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>  //for strcpy method
int main()
{
    char sweet[5];
    strcpy(sweet,"kava")
    printf("My favorite sweet is %s\n", sweet);

    return 0;
}
```

Let me know if you are still facing any problem.

Comment: This statement "constant character pointer " is qrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Correction appreciated Sir :-)

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, you can declare an array, and define it later:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char x[];
int main() {
  extern char y[6];
  puts(x);
  puts(y);
}
char x[6] = "hello";
char y[6] = "world";
```

But the initializers must be constant values.
Note that without `extern`, `y` in `main()` would be an uninitialized array, different from the `y[]` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `char str[5];`, you **declare and define** an array of five chars, **define** means `str` stores some memory address and can't be changed.

When you write `str = "hello"`, you assign an different address of a string to `str`, this is not allowed.